# Why was the SASS deprecated in favour of SCSS?

Tags: sass

Basically, why SCSS, instead of SASS? The shorthand of SASS was the main reason why I picked up SASS, I recently came back to it and realised that it is no longer in favour. Any reasons why?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Sass has two syntaxes. The new main
>   syntax (as of Sass 3) is known as
>   “SCSS” (for “Sassy CSS”), and is a
>   superset of CSS3’s syntax. **This means
>   that every valid CSS3 stylesheet is
>   valid SCSS as well.** SCSS files use the
>   extension .scss.
>
> The second, older syntax is known as
>   the indented syntax (or just “Sass”).
>   Inspired by Haml’s terseness, it’s
>   **intended for people who prefer
>   conciseness over similarity to CSS.**
>   Instead of brackets and semicolons, it
>   uses the indentation of lines to
>   specify blocks. Although no longer the
>   primary syntax, the indented syntax
>   will continue to be supported. Files
>   in the indented syntax use the
>   extention .sass.

Source: http://sass-lang.com/

If you like sass more than scss you are free to use it! scss is for people who don't like the indented syntax. And it is extremely easy to convert a css file to scss beacause scss is  a superset of css.

That it is no longer in favor is probably because the developers like scss more. But this is a matter of taste. I personally still prefer sass.

Comment: Sass's "weird" syntax is one of the big objections people had to it. I like it for its concision, but SCSS tends to freak people out less, so it is a reasonable default.

Comment: I agree! But I like sass more for the same reasons you do.

Comment: My little fingers don't like to press shift keys a lot, so I like SASS either.

Comment: If some people used to code in something like Python where intendation is required then they might feel more familar with SASS. Reason why SCSS is prefered is simply because it's nearly like CSS3 and anyone who starts with stylesheet is CSS first choice hence the faster relation to SCSS

Comment: @Thielicious SCSS not nearly like CSS, but a superset of CSS, that means every valid CSS file ist also a valid SCSS file, which helps by migrating or copying code from CSS sources

Comment: @jigfox "SCSS not nearly like CSS, but a superset of CSS" Uhm, excuse but I'm not talking about superset, you can still use it like CSS. It doesn't matter if it's a superset of it or not.