# Why SASS stopped being the primary syntax (now SCSS is the one)?

Tags: sass

In the [official webpage](http://sass-lang.com/) they say:

> Although no longer the primary syntax,
>   the indented syntax will continue to
>   be supported.

Doe anybody know why SCSS "partially took over" SASS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was the SASS deprecated in favour of SCSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000690/why-was-the-sass-deprecated-in-favour-of-scss)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concepts that Sass addresses aren't obvious to designers, and this means that Sass has always been misunderstood as nothing more than a different, quirky syntax for writing CSS.

(LESS.css has gained a little buzz among designers, probably because its syntax is more similar to CSS — even though Sass is more capable and robust, regardless of syntax.)

Because Sass is a language for authoring styleshets, it needs to be approachable to designers. The whitespace-aware Sass syntax is perceived as a "completely different" language with little functional gain, and the different syntax isn't everyone's cup of tea. The valuable concepts like variables, mixins, subclasses (@extends), unit arithmetic, color math, etc. go right over people's heads if they can't get past the "weird" syntax.

SCSS was designed to be a true *superset* of CSS. This means anyone can start with a plain CSS file and their knowledge of CSS, and then introduce concepts gradually without being overwhelmed.

The `sass-convert` utility makes the choice of syntax a moot point: if you prefer Sass over SCSS like I do, it's easy to switch.

Comment: I've been playing with sass too, how are you using it? Together with Compass or just with ruby? (are you using Haml too?).

Comment: Yes, I always use compass with sass: it adds a lot of helpful idioms and utilities.

Comment: Problem is now, you want to use real sass, forgot some syntax, want to get your hand on some docs… you're pretty much fuc3ked. thanks designers