# How to express SCSS declared variable for tag names in SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

I've seen [at this location](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/sass-things-links/) a snippet for managing anchor tags in SCSS and I liked how the guy declared all the tags' pseudo types as a variable and used it later on "all at once".

```
$a-tags: 'a, a:active, a:hover, a:visited';
$a-tags-hover: 'a:active, a:hover';

#{$a-tags} { color: red; text-decoration: none; }
#{$a-tags-hover} { color: blue; }
```

I'm curious if this is somehow possible in pure SASS as well. I haven't got it to work. The following is one of the attempts and since I'm new to SASSing, I'm pretty sure my troubleshooting sucks.

```
$a-tags: 'a, a:active, a:hover, a:visited'
$a-tags-hover: 'a:active, a:hover'

#$a-tags
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
#$a-tags-hover
  color: blue;
```

I've tried out several different variants, keeping the curly braces and also omitting them in the tag name etc. No luck - no style seems to be rendered on my anchor tags.

What am I missing?

Comment: The snippet in the first part of your question is correct, the one you are trying is the old syntax and might fail with the new compiler.

Comment: You should keep the brackets for compiling the `variables`: `#{$a-tags}`  and `#{$a-tags-hover}`

Comment: @Mr.Alien Could you elaborate, please? According to all the stuff I've been reading lately, it's supposed to be LESS that got obsolete because of of SCSS that is about to get overridden by SASS with its cleaner syntax. Am I totally off and wrong on this one? Please do tell.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Would you post it as an answer?

Comment: @AndyJ Yes.. you are totally wrong. LESS and SASS are two different CSS pre processers. SCSS was deprecated and SASS is the new one. The syntax which you are using is SCSS deprecated syntax.

Comment: @Mr.Alien are you sure about `scss` is being deprecated? From all I know that's quite unlikely to happen anytime soon. Could you please provide some documentation? Thank you. I do believe it's [the other way around](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3000787/1891677)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Yes, the other way round :) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Sass version (not SCSS)

```
 $a-tags:       'a, a:active, a:hover, a:visited'
 $a-tags-hover: 'a:active, a:hover'

 #{$a-tags}
   color: red
   text-decoration: none
 #{$a-tags-hover}
   color: blue
```